# How to create login field properties depending on which radio button is checked

Tags: javascript

I have a login page with 2 radio buttons "new account" and "existing user".  when "new account" is selected the "User" field auto populates with the text "New Account" and the "Password" field remains blank.  I need to grey out the fields so that they are uneditable when the "new account" radio button is selected, but still pass along the information in the fields because it is used to gain access to the database.  I can disable the fields to get the desired uneditable greyed out fields, but the information does not get passed along to the database.

I have tried to fix this by creating two hidden fields (which auto populate with the needed information for database access) to take the place of the "user" and "password" field which allows me to disable the visible fields while "new account" radio button is clicked and which still passes along the new user login info that never changes.  This works fine until I try to login as an existing user, in which case my two hidden fields do not auto populate with the users input for their existing account information.

There may be a much simpler approach to fixing this problem, but all of my research and trials have not been successful yet.  I have been reluctant to ask this question as it seems so simple and frequently used approach for a login page, but all of my searching has not yielded any thing that has worked yet.  I appreciate any input or navigation in the right direction.

Comment: How are you passing the field values to the database? Can you post a mock-up of your problem in JSFiddle?

Comment: ...and please note that the values of *disabled* form fields will (usually) not be send to the server (by the browser).

Comment: Getting disabled textbox values is straightforward eg http://jsfiddle.net/rxVPP/1/ - However as Marc says - if you are relying on the POSTing to return the value you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the correct and painless solution for your problem is to use **two** different form tags (take care to not nest them) and show/hide the form depending on the selected radio button.

And for the convenience of your user you should copy the username from one form to the other if he has already filled the user field and switches to the other version later.

**EDIT**

The complete solution:

*HTML*

```
<label><input class="formSwitcher" type="radio" name="formSwitch" data-form="#divForm1"> Form 1</label>
<label><input class="formSwitcher" type="radio" name="formSwitch" data-form="#divForm2"> Form 2</label>

<hr>    

<div class="hiddenForm" id="divForm1">Put form 1 in here</div>
<div class="hiddenForm" id="divForm2">Put form 2 in here</div>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​*JS*

```
// if someone clicks on one radio button
$('.formSwitcher')​​​​.change(function(){
    // get the form id we want to show (from the "data-form" attribute)
    var formIdToChange = $(this).data('form');
    // hide all forms first
    $('.hiddenForm').hide();
    // show the specific form
    $(formIdToChange).show();
});

​// initially hide all forms
$('.hiddenForm').hide();
// initially call the change method if one radio is already selected on page load
$('.formSwitcher:checked').change();​
```

Comment: Thanks Marc for that idea, the only trouble I have is I am not positive on how to follow through with it. I am able to create the two forms, but when it comes to showing/hiding a form based on radio buttons I get lost. I have found code to do this, but don't think I am using it properly... here is the original code I have started with http://jsfiddle.net/ajdietrich/V53kM/2/   does this next code look capable of creating the show/hide form feature I am looking for?   http://jsfiddle.net/ajdietrich/RLTDV/

Comment: All a bit complicated mate :) As you already have the almighty jQuery it is pretty easy to set up such a switch, please see my updated answer or see it up and running in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/V53kM/3/

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you need to change the existing user fields because they will grant access to the database? I think what you want to do is to change the properties of fields depending on what is selected. For example if you need the auto populate fields to be set when the user clicks new user then write something like

```
document.form.AutoPopUser.value="required value"
```

and when the person clicks on the existing user you can do

`document.form.AutoPopUser.value=""`

or if even having that part exist will mess up the existing user log in then you could delete that entire section by putting it inside a div and creating or destroying it depending on the selected option. I feel like I'm not being very clear but I think what you need is a clever set of onClick functions to get rid of things you dont need and add in the ones you do need. If you could post some code to go with this that would be awesome.

Comment: Thanks for your reply champ, I am not having trouble with the auto populate portion.  You hit the nail on the head about the clever onclick functions, trouble is I'm not clever enough yet to write that type of code.